# AngularJS require module on-demand

Tags: angularjs, module, dependencies, lazy-loading

Is it possible to load lazy and include module to requires of another module on-demand? Something like that:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.btnClick=function(){    
       (function(d,s,id){
           var js, fjs= d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if(d.getElementById(id)) return;
           js= d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
           js.onload=function(){
               // do something to make myApp dependent on anotherModule,
               //like if it were loaded initially: myApp=angular.module('myApp',['anotherModule']);
           };
           js.src='/js/anotherModule.js';
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }(document,'script','my_id'));
    }
}]);
```

I want to use directive from `'anotherModule'` on `$scope.btnClick()` is triggered.

Comment: why would you want to do that inside a controller?

Comment: because I want it to be loaded on user click the button. In most cases there is no need to load anotherModule.js initially. actually, it's not important for me to do it inside controller, another way to lazy-load it also may fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless your modules are very large, i'd recommend against lazy loading because requests are expensive. it is faster to load one big file than many small files

if you're concerned about performance you should consider first optimizing by concatenation/minification/uglification

heres a good resource about optimizing your site: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: so, if angular can't do it itself, seems more reasonable to add my required on-demand module to my big .js file. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature in Angular 1 for that.

nevertheless [oc-LazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) achieves this.

Comment: nice decision, but it takes more size than the file I want to be loaded. Thank you.